# Orchard CMS - create vertical Navigation Menu next to Home

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I am new to Orchard and trying to figure out how it works code-wise.
So, I have created a custom Content Type through the code and i am able to create Content Items under this Content Type. i have the 'Show on the Menu' checkbox on the editor page of the Content item. But when I check it and select the menu to which i want this newly created custom item to be added, it gets added as a vertical menu item whereas i need it to be added as a vertical submenu to one of the root items.
Please find images which describe what is happening now and what I need.
[Current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh0UK.png)
[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cN5l.png)

Product2 is a custom content item and should be added as a entry in the vertical menu as shown in the 2nd image

Comment: Have you fully read [this documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Navigation-and-menus/)?

Comment: @devqon Yes I did. But the documentation describes the Dashboard way to create submenu, whereas I need a way to do this through code. Also, i tried using IMenuProvider and created the MainMenu class, but that just adds menu items as mentioned in the image named "Current Behavior".
Also, i want to add the menu items to a new Menu that I have created and not the default Main Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is rather complex. There are several steps involved.

1. **Understanding how to create a child theme**

   See the [official documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-the-default-theme/), create a child theme and enable it
2. **Understanding the concept of shape alternates**

   See the [official documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes/)
3. **Configure the menu in admin area**

   Go to the admin area, click on *Navigation* in the menu and add some menu items and sub items, for example

   ```
   [ Home (Content Menu Item) ]
   [ Service (Content Menu Item) ]
     [ Document Storage (Custom Link) ]
   ```

   Once you have this structure Orchard renders this structure via a `@Zone(Model.Navigation)` call in a theme. You have to search where this call is located for yourself, it depends on the theme.

   My child theme uses a `Layout.cshtml` alternate which calls `@Zone(Model.Navigation)` where needed like so

   ```
   @{
     Func<dynamic, dynamic> Zone = x => Display(x); // Zone as an alias for Display to help make it obvious when we're displaying zones
   }

   <div class="wrapper">
       @* Navigation bar *@
       @if (Model.Navigation != null)
       {
         <div id="layout-navigation" class="group navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
           @Zone(Model.Navigation)
         </div>
       }

       ...
   </div>
   ```

   Now, if Orchard renders the menu itself, it uses the `Menu.cshtml` shape template, thus the next step will be to provide a shape alternate for `Menu.cshtml`.
4. **Creating a shape alternate for the menu in your child theme**

   Go to you child theme folder and add a file `Views\Menu.cshtml` and start rendering the menu there, for example

   ```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     @DisplayChildren(Model)
   </ul>
   ```

   The `@DisplayChildren(Model)` call will start rendering the menu items via the `MenuItem.cshtml` shape template, thus the next step will be to provide a shape alternate for `MenuItem.cshtml`.
5. **Creating a shape alternate for menu items in your child theme**

   Go to you child theme folder and add a file `Views\MenuItem.cshtml` and start rendering the menu items. Here is the content of my `MenuItem.cshtml` file, which renders the menu items as `<li>` structure according to the bootstrap specs:

   ```
   @*
     this shape alternate is displayed when a <li> element is rendered
     whereas the following code is based on Orchard.Core\Shapes\Views\Menu.cshtml
   *@

   @{
       // odd formatting in this file is to cause more attractive results in the output.
       var items = Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model);
   }
   @{
       if (!HasText(Model.Text)) {
           @DisplayChildren(Model)
       }
       else {
           if ((bool) Model.Selected) {
               Model.Classes.Add("current");
           }

           if (items.Any()) {
               Model.Classes.Add("dropdown");
           }

           @* morphing the shape to keep Model untouched*@
           Model.Metadata.Alternates.Clear();
           Model.Metadata.Type = "MenuItemLink";

           @* render the menu item only if it has some content *@
           var renderedMenuItemLink = Display(Model);
           if (HasText(renderedMenuItemLink)) {
               var tag = Tag(Model, "li");
               @tag.StartElement
               @renderedMenuItemLink

               if (items.Any()) {
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       @DisplayChildren(Model)
                   </ul>
               }

               @tag.EndElement
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   You can also provide alternates to override specific menu item types like the `Custom Link`. The file would then be `MenuItemLink.cshtml` with a content like

   ```
   @* 
     this shape alternate is displayed when menu link is _not_ of type "Content Menu Item" otherwise MenuItemLink-ContentMenuItem.cshtml is used
     whereas the following code is based on Orchard.Core\Shapes\Views\MenuItemLink.cshtml
   *@
   <a href="@Model.Href" @if (Model.Item.Items.Length > 0) { <text>class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"</text> }>@Model.Text</a>
   ```

   As you can see, a lot of work but pretty flexible.